# How do I encode a 4-byte string as a single 32-bit integer?

Tags: c#, python, algorithm, powershell

First, a disclaimer. I'm not a CS grad nor a math major, so simplicity is important.

I have a four-character string (e.g. "isoy") that I need to pass as a single 32-bit integer field. Of course at the other end, I need to decode it back to a string. The string will only contain A-Z, and case is not important, if that helps.

The funny part is that I'm starting with PowerShell on the sending end and Linux at the receiving end. I can use Perl or Python there, with a preference for Python. I don't actually need answers in each language, I'm most interested in a PowerShell (C# also good) example for going both ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To 32-bit unsigned integer:

```
uint x = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("isoy"), 0); // 2037347177
```

To string:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(x));      // "isoy"
```

[BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) uses the native endianness of the machine.

Comment: $s = "isoy";                                                        $x = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($s),0); $s = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([BitConverter]::GetBytes($x));

Answer (score 8):

For Python, [struct.unpack](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.pack#struct.pack) does the job (to make a 4-byte string into an int -- `struct.pack` goes the other way):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('i', 'isoy')[0]
2037347177
>>> struct.pack('i', 2037347177)
'isoy'
>>>
```

(you can use different formats to ensure big-endian or little-endian encoding, if you need that -- `'>i'` and `'<i'` respectively -- instead of just plain `'i'` which uses whatever encoding is native to the machine).

Comment: The code works, but for Python 3.7.3 it should be: `struct.unpack('i', b'isoy')[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
// string -> int    

uint ret = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
  ret |= ( str[i] << ( i * 8 ) );
}

// int -> string
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
  str[i] = ( ret >> ( i * 8 ) ) & 0xff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using PowerShell syntax you can do it this way (pretty much like dtb solution):

```
PS> $x = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32([byte[]][char[]]'isoy', 0)
PS> [char[]][BitConverter]::GetBytes($x) -join ''
isoy
```

You do have to watch out for endian-ness on the Linux side.  If it is running on an Intel processor I believe should be fine (same endian-ness as the PowerShell side).

Comment: Wow, power shell syntax is heinous.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the struct standard library module in Python's Manual. It has two functions for this: `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`. You can use the 'L' (unsigned long) format character for this.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from byte packing, you can also consider that your 26-character alphabet can be encoded as 0-25 instead of A-Z.

So without worrying about big and little endians, you can go from "letters" to a number like this:

```
val=letter0+letter1*26+letter2*26*26+letter3*26*26*26;
```

to go from val back to letters, you do something like this:

```
letter0=val%26;
letter1=(val/26)%26;
letter2=(val/(26*26))%26;
letter3=(val/(26*26*26))%26;
```

where "%" is your language's modulus operator and "/" is an integer division.

You'll obviously need a way to get from 'A'-'Z' to 0-25 and back. That's language dependent.

You can easily put this into loops. I show the loops unrolled to make things a bit more obvious.

It's more common to pack letters into bytes, so you can use **shift** and **and** bitwise operations to encode and decode. But by doing it the way I show above, you could pack **six** letters into a 32-bit number, rather than just four. Which is nice, since you can hold things like stock market ticker symbols in a single 32-bit value (mutual funds ticker symbols are 5 characters).